# What is LIMIT clause in PDO PHP?

Tags: php, pdo, limit

Simple and forward. What is LIMIT clause in PDO PHP ? Since I could not find an answer anywhere I have a feeling its something stupid simple.

Comment: [http://www.roseindia.net/sql/sql-functions/mysql-limit.shtml](http://www.roseindia.net/sql/sql-functions/mysql-limit.shtml)

Comment: I do not see any reference to PDO in that article.

Comment: @SalmanA limit is about mysql, not pdo. you should learn the roles of PDO and Mysql in the system first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#id892888) is MySql-specific syntax that instructs the server to return only a portion of the full result set that your query produces. It applies to any code that talks to MySql, not only PDO or PHP.

Comment: So if I set LIMIT to 20, my SELECT query will return only the first 20 rows ?

Comment: @mixix: Yes, but you can also try it and see :)